# a href no funciona al darle click en el carrusel (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, href, carrusel

tengo este codigo con html y css. Es un carrusel con tres tarjetas (imagen, titulo, texto y link a otra página) y a sus costados las flechas para desplazarse. Cuando le doy click a los enlaces de las tarjetas no funcionan. Parecieran como textos normales.
¿Alguien podría decirme cual es el problema? Ya lo he revisado y no veo que es lo que esta mal.
Dejo parte del código:

```css
.carrousel {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 2em;
}

.item {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.tarjetaCarrusel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.flechasCarrusel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 120%;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -50px;
  right: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth
}

.flechasCarrusel a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.flechasCarrusel a i {
  font-size: 42px;
}
```

```html
<div class="carrousel">
  <div class="item" id="item-1">

    <div class="tarjetaCarrusel" id="tarjeta-1">
      <img src="imagen1.jpg" alt="Imagen 1">
      <h3>AC/DC regresa con "Realize"</h3>
      <p>AC/DC ha presentado otra canción de su nuevo álbum Power Up (...)</p>
      <a href="https://ibero909.fm/blog/acdc-regresa-con-realize-en-preparacin-para-su-nuevo-lbum" target="_blank">Leer más</a>
    </div>

    <div class="flechasCarrusel">
      <a href="#item-3"> <i> <span class="material-icons-outlined">
                    arrow_back_ios
                    </span></i> </a>
      <a href="#item-2"> <i> <span class="material-icons-outlined">
                    arrow_forward_ios
                    </span></i> </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tienes un div por sobre otro,  pon `background-color:red` a `flechasCarrusel` y vas a ver tu problema

Comment: Ahh, si ya veo. Como cambio esa superposición?